# NavigationItem in Master/Detail application

Tags: ios, uinavigationitem

I wrote a Master/Detail Application by using the Master/Detail template of XCode. After starting the app, the title of the navigation button for the master view is just "Master". Now I waant tio rename that button, but unfortunately I don't know how to access this button. 
In appdelegate.m there is the following code to initialize the views:

```
MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];

DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController]
```

I tried these ways without success:

```
masterViewController.navigationItem.title = @"newTitle";
```

or

```
masterNavigationController.navigationItem.title = @"newTitle";
```

As I wasn't sure, if the name of the button is just the title of the view behind idt, I also tried that:

masterViewController.title = @"newTitle";

Nothing worked. But as the title of the button is "Master" and I definitely didn't set it, I believe there must be some way to set it. Does anyone know how to do it?

Just to show the button:
[image]

Comment: The navigation button? Are you talking about the back button?

Comment: Maybe... I really don't know if it is the back button or the navigation button. It is the only button that appears after the app is started. I can use it to make the MasterView appear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you would have created Master/Detail application using Master/Detail Template, then go to your `"MasterViewController.m"` file and change the string "Master" as you wanted. See the below image it would be like this in your `MasterViewController.m`. 
[image]

**UPDATE:**
and also change the `barButtonItem` name in the `DetailViewController.m` as like below. This will do the trick.
[image]

Comment: That was exactly what I did. But meanwhile, I changed my init method and inside it I set the title with a simple string: self.title = @"newTitle" And this only changes the headline in the view but not the title of the button!

Answer (score 1):

try `self.navigationItem.title = @"newTitle";` inside viewDidLoad() of MasterViewController.m file. or `self.title = @"newTitle"` inside the init() method. HTH.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work. Isn't it the samr as masterViewController.title=@"newTitle"?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are trying to change the title of the back button property.
This is done by putting the following code in the `-viewDidLoad` method of `MasterViewController`.

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"newTitle" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while and somehow with the current Xcode Version 8.3.2 it works different:

If you would have created Master/Detail application using Master/Detail Template, then go to your `Main.storyboard` and select the `Master` in the `Master Scene` and then show the "Attributes Inspector". In the Navigation item area you can change the `Title`.

You can do this for `Master` as well as `Detail`.
[image]